# Some ideas how to personalize Wordpress articles content area as in this blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress world and I came from Joomla that have a pretty different content management logic...

I would like to create a blog that is present in similarly to this one (this is made using WP):

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/

My doubt is related about how the articles preview are shown in homepage: as you can see an articles are presented in two columns of template (and this is not proble...I can use two aligned div using float CSS sttribute) but I don't know how to show an article preview as this blog.

For each article ih home page I need to show:

1. The title of the article.
2. A short introduction (a fixed number of words or character take by the article body)
3. An immage thumb (if it exist in the article, for example the first immage of the article)

Using Joomla I can put modules that implement this functionality into content area of my template but I think to understand that, using Word Press, I have to implement this presentation logic with some PHP lines

Do you have some idea about how do it?

Tnx so much

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would find a theme that would match what you are trying to accomplish if you are not familiar with the platform.  Here would be a quick example of a direction I would go for your site.

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/pure-line

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/magazine-basic

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/sampression-lite

From this point you would just have to look at how the posts are carried and how they are displayed.  There are many loops that will help accomplish what you want and here is a reference link to wordpress coding section also known as codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/

Some combination of items I would use would be

The Image

Get Attachment Image: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

The Post - Title

Get Posts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

The "short introduction"

Get Excerpt: http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt

Comment: tnx so much...with regard to the template you suggested to me.

Have you suggested to me those templates only because they have two columns? or because have some others features? Can I use all template having 3 or more columns?

Tnx so much

Andrea

Comment: I suggested them cause they have a similar look to what you want.  I would go through and see other themes where they have the ability to change the layout as well.  Also remember you have the ability to set a widget section to most of the theme's for a third section for various other types of functions.